# MVC with Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: php, cordova, laravel, model-view-controller, phalcon

Most MVC-frameworks (e.g. Phalcon or Laravel) use PHP, or some other script language that uses curly brackets, and placeholders in view-templates and connect them to models and controllers. 
 Each HTML-page that is outputted to the browser goes through PHP to fill-in data or variables.

But how would you create a Cordova app with that? It seems the only way would be to write all HTML and JS yourself and connect through PHP CRUD services. The templating could be done client-side, with AngularJS or some other Javascript framework. But the PHP views and controllers don't seem to play a role then anymore, so what's the point of still using an MVC framework in PHP then?

So my question is : in what way could PHP MVC-frameworks and Cordova be used together?  And if not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: MVC is a back-end pattern. If you want to build the whole front-end with JavaScript, that's fine. Angular is a popular solution for this. But the fact remains, you still need a backend. Choosing whether or not to use the MVC pattern doesn't mean you can't use a particular framework. I don't see the contradiction. For example, it's common for MVC applications to require ajax capabilities, and for the same application to serve both the JSON and the HTML. You could use a multi-module MVC application, with one dedicated for HTML and the other for JSON and thus share the same business logic.

Comment: I see you asked a similar question [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247839/need-your-opinion-advice-about-my-php-framework), perhaps your questions regarding your framework would be better-suited for more of an opinionated audience such as stackoverflow's PHP [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php).

Comment: Yes, my framework is really giving me headaches about that to do with it. This question is specifically about having a client (Cordova) that can't use dynamically generated HTML pages.

Comment: I can see the point of sharing business logic, but that would only be the model then, since the controller in MVC has such a strong connection with the view (template), or am I wrong there?

Comment: JavaScript, when ran on the front-end, becomes your controller layer. Ajax takes input and gives you a response, manipulating your data, and becomes your model layer. Just as a controller can interact with multiple models, JavaScript can make multiple HTTP Requests. When you get your response, JavaScript, your controller layer, would use logic to figure out which view to use. Finally, after deciding which view to use, you'd have dedicated JavaScript functions as your view layer. JavaScript can manipulate HTML using the DOM methods, so the whole system should work, if written well.